# Apache redirect only part of a query

Tags: regex, apache, url-rewriting, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm trying to redirect a query string to a non query url. It looks something like this.

Original
`http://searchtest.help.org/search?client=Cool_Sub&site=Cool_Sub&proxystylesheet=Cool_Sub&q=stackoverflow`

Expected result
`https://searchtest.help.org/cool-search/stackoverflow`

I only want to grab the last part of the query. In this case **stackoverflow**.

This part will always be static.

> search?client=Cool_Sub&site=Cool_Sub&proxystylesheet=Cool_Sub&q=

I'm using this in my apache vhost

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/search$

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^client=Cool_Sub&site=Cool_Sub&proxystylesheet=Cool_Sub&q=(.*)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://searchtest.help.org/cool-search/%1 [R=301,L]
```

However the results with that is
`https://searchtest.help.org/cool-search/stackoverflow?client=Cool_Sub&site=Cool_Sub&proxystylesheet=Cool_Sub&q=stackoverflow`

I've tried many variations of the above rule but no dice. Any assistance would be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Add `QSD` flag to your RewriteRule

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://searchtest.help.org/cool-search/%1 [R=301,QSD,L]
```

According to Apache 2.4 documentation:

> When the requested URI contains a query string, and the target URI
>   does not, the default behavior of RewriteRule is to copy that query
>   string to the target URI. Using the [QSD] flag causes the query string
>   to be discarded.